# Tell MS Word to ignore a block of text

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

Is there a way designate a block of text that Word should ignore and not change or do anything to? I have a macro which removes multiple periods and all the extra and double-spaces in the entire document. I like to copy National Weather Services alerts into my diary that use plain text, create ellipses with three periods, and use multiple spaces to do formatting to create indents and lists. I want to tell Word don’t touch this block of text, but the text above and below are normal.

Comment: You will need to modify the macro to ignore text that is identified by some property, perhaps style. Include the macro in your post for a better answer.

Comment: "If you want to limit the changes to your document to certain areas (for instance, single paragraphs or lines), you can also do this using the Restrict Editing menu." https://www.groovypost.com/howto/protect-parts-of-a-word-document-from-editing/

Comment: You could select the text and use the Group control on the Developer tab.

Comment: Thank you I guess Restrict Editing is the only way to do it. I had actually seen it on my own and it is a colossal multi-step pain in the arse to use, meaning I won't use it. I had hoped there was a way as simple as selecting a block of text and just designating it read only.